# Neo4j Cypher command to delete both the node and the unique constraints associated with it?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want a particular node to get deleted from `Neo4j` with all the unique constraints (if any) associated with it.

We all know that the command
`MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE (n)` deletes the node but if the node has any unique constraint and(or) indexing related to it, it fails to remove or delete those along with the node.

Is there any modifications that can be done to the delete query for to delete the node and also the unique constraints attached along with it. All the unique constraints of every node type can be checked using the query:
call `db.indexes()`;

In case if there is no such single command, then can the call `db.indexes()` be modified such that only the unique constraints are displayed whose label (type) is known?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even if one deletes all the nodes associated with an index or constraint, one generally wants to retain the index or constraint in case new relevant nodes are added later. So, there is no single Cypher command to drop all relevant nodes AND their indexes and constraints at the same time.

There are, however, separate Cypher clauses for doing those things. The documentation for dropping indexes is in [this section](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/index/#query-schema-index-introduction), and for dropping the various kinds of constraints is in the relevant sections on [this page](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/constraints/).

Comment: Okay, since the answer is no. Can you add the answer of the last part of the question. It might be useful to many of us.

Comment: There are 2 ways to drop indexes and 4 ways to drop constraints. (And there may be more ways later,) That is why I gave links instead of writing a very long answer.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through those links. I couldn't find what I am actually searching for. I want to drop the constraints but without writing the unique constraints i.e. only by label. Does such query exists?

Comment: Or else other solution to my problem can be to fetch the results of call db.indexes(). I want to get the filtered result of the above. Basically, the unique constraints or properties that are unique (even when the node is deleted) by the label (type) or tokenNames

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. There are often ways to get what you want after trying things out. Then if you still have an issue, pose a new question and show what you have tried.